# Doctrine persist listener

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

There is a listener on flush:

```
$evm->addEventListener('onFlush', new Doctrine\Listeners\FlushListener());
```

Is there listener that is triggered on persist:

```
$entityManager->persist($entity);
```

Answer (score 2):

Right from [the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events):

> 9.2. Lifecycle Events
>
> [...]
>
> prePersist - The prePersist event occurs for a given entity before the
>   respective EntityManager persist operation for that entity is
>   executed. It should be noted that this event is only triggered on
>   initial persist of an entity (i.e. it does not trigger on future
>   updates).
>
> postPersist - The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the
>   entity has been made persistent. It will be invoked after the database
>   insert operations. Generated primary key values are available in the
>   postPersist event.

Comment: so I add "$evm->addEventListener('postPersist'" and in the listener I have "public function postPersists(\Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs $args)" but it has no effect

Comment: the function name should be **postPersist**, no final "s"

Comment: but im taling about EVENTS not LIFECYCLE

Comment: I do not understand... Those **are** events.